# how can transfer information of one view to another view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

this is my View

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("Index");  
<fieldset>
    <legend>emp</legend>

    <div class="display-label">name</div>
    <div class="display-field">
     <!--   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name) -->
     @Html.DropDownList("gett","--SELECT--")
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">address</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("address","--SELECT--")
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
    }
```

i want to send information of this view to "Index" action of Home controller. But i am unable to reach on Index by clicking Submit button. whenever i pree submit button, no action is performed. Please check my code. and suggest me what should i add to forward my values selected in dropdownlist Index.

Comment: I have found the reason for not forwarding from view to Index is that we have to write name of controller also. this  @{ Html.BeginForm("Index","Home"); } is correct way to transfer. Now please tell me how can use values of these dropdown list on Index contrller.?

Comment: Nobody has answer of this question..?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.mvcform.aspx

You should be using

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))   {
```

and that is assuming you are going to the current controllers index method, otherwise you need to specify the controller name as well

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "WhateverControllerName")) {

}
```

since you don't have html.beginform in a using stmt, I dont think your ending form tag is getting rendered.